# React-Table resetting to page 1 when I add data

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a react table with pages that works with me adding new data to the collection however when ever data is added it always resets the current page to 0. Is there some way to save the current state of what page is currently selected? I cant figure out based of this code I have from a fellow what I need to change in order for this to not keep resetting the page index.

My table code looks like this

````js
function Table({ columns, data }) {
    const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
            // Add a new fuzzyTextFilterFn filter type.
            fuzzyText: fuzzyTextFilterFn,
            // Or, override the default text filter to use
            // "startWith"
            text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
                return rows.filter(row => {
                    const rowValue = row.values[id]
                    return rowValue !== undefined
                        ? String(rowValue)
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase())
                        : true
                })
            },
        }),
        []
    )

    const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
            // Let's set up our default Filter UI
            Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
        }),
        []
    )

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
        state,
        visibleColumns,
        preGlobalFilteredRows,
        setGlobalFilter,
        page,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageOptions,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        selectedPage,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            defaultColumn, // Be sure to pass the defaultColumn option
            filterTypes,
            initialState: { pageIndex: 0}

        },
        useFilters, // useFilters!
        useGlobalFilter, // useGlobalFilter!
        usePagination
    )

    // We don't want to render all of the rows for this example, so cap
    // it for this use case
    //const firstPageRows = rows.slice(0, 10)

    return (
        <>
            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                            <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                {column.render('Header')}
                                {/* Render the columns filter UI */}
                                <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}    
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {page.map((row, i) => {
                    prepareRow(row)
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
            {/*<div>Showing the first 20 results of {rows.length} rows</div>*/}
            <div className="pagination">
                <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    {'<<'}
                </button>{' '}
                <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    {'<'}
                </button>{' '}
                <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    {'>'}
                </button>{' '}
                <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    {'>>'}
                </button>{' '}
                <span>
          Page{' '}
                    <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{' '}
        </span>
                <span>
          | Go to page:{' '}
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        defaultValue={pageIndex}
                        onChange={e => {
                            const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
                            gotoPage(page)
                        }}
                        style={{ width: '100px' }}
                    />
        </span>{' '}
                <select
                    value={pageSize}
                    onChange={e => {
                        setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
                    }}
                >
                    {[10, 20, 30, 40].map(pageSize => (
                        <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                            Show {pageSize}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}```
````

Answer (score 5):

You might not need to save the current state of what page is currently selected. All you need to do is set *autoselect* option on your table to false.
Your code should look like this

```
function Table({ columns, data }) {
const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
        // Add a new fuzzyTextFilterFn filter type.
        fuzzyText: fuzzyTextFilterFn,
        // Or, override the default text filter to use
        // "startWith"
        text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
            return rows.filter(row => {
                const rowValue = row.values[id]
                return rowValue !== undefined
                    ? String(rowValue)
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase())
                    : true
            })
        },
    }),
    []
)

const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
        // Let's set up our default Filter UI
        Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
    }),
    []
)

const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    visibleColumns,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    selectedPage,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
} = useTable(
    {
        columns,
        data,
        defaultColumn, // Be sure to pass the defaultColumn option
        filterTypes,
        initialState: { pageIndex: 0},
        autoResetPage: false, //this change should be made

    },
    useFilters, // useFilters!
    useGlobalFilter, // useGlobalFilter!
    usePagination
)

// We don't want to render all of the rows for this example, so cap
// it for this use case
//const firstPageRows = rows.slice(0, 10)

return (
    <>
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                        <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                            {column.render('Header')}
                            {/* Render the columns filter UI */}
                            <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
                        </th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            ))}    
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {page.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row)
                return (
                    <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                        {row.cells.map(cell => {
                            return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>
                )
            })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        {/*<div>Showing the first 20 results of {rows.length} rows</div>*/}
        <div className="pagination">
            <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                {'<<'}
            </button>{' '}
            <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                {'<'}
            </button>{' '}
            <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                {'>'}
            </button>{' '}
            <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                {'>>'}
            </button>{' '}
            <span>
      Page{' '}
                <strong>
        {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
      </strong>{' '}
    </span>
            <span>
      | Go to page:{' '}
                <input
                    type="number"
                    defaultValue={pageIndex}
                    onChange={e => {
                        const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
                        gotoPage(page)
                    }}
                    style={{ width: '100px' }}
                />
    </span>{' '}
            <select
                value={pageSize}
                onChange={e => {
                    setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
                }}
            >
                {[10, 20, 30, 40].map(pageSize => (
                    <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                        Show {pageSize}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    </>
)}
```

The answer is found on [this](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes) page of the docs